# Формат заголовка HTML4

Tags: html

Какой заголовок у html4?

Я обычно использую такой

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
<title>Документ без названия</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Взято с [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp) перевод вольный.

---

**HTML 4.01 Strict**

Этот DTD включает все HTML элементы и аттрибуты, но НЕ ВКЛЮЧАЕТ экспериментальные или устаревшие элементы (например font). Framesets не поддерживаются.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

**HTML 4.01 Transitional**

Этот DTD включает все HTML элементы и аттрибуты, также ВКЛЮЧАЕТ экспериментальные или устаревшие элементы (например font). Framesets не поддерживаются.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

**HTML 4.01 Frameset**

Этот DTD эквивалентен HTML 4.01 Transitional, но включает поддержку frameset.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
```

Comment: P.S а у Вас заголовок XHTML 1.0 Transitional

Comment: не могу понять где конкретно используют эти отличия (я про XHTML)

не встречал еще сайтов на которых бы для чего то использовали XHTML

обычно это просто заголовок

Comment: xhtml подразумевает, что страница- это валидный xml, вот и все отличия

Comment: так вот и не понятно кто ее потом использует как xml

Comment: помню у меня Samsung D220 мог одну и ту же страницу в которой не было указано никаких размеров элементов при доктайп хтмл4 показать с горизонтальным скроллом, а икс-хтмл показывал по ширине экрана. Значит как-то использовалось.

Answer (score -1):

пишите `<!doctype html>` и не ломайте себе голову [тык](http://htmlbook.ru/html/!doctype)